# PHP require "failed to open stream"

Tags: php, apache, slim

Hi I'm having an issue with a example program I'm making in PHP using the Slim framework.

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image: Error In HTML]

As you can see, PHP (or Apache) can't open my validate file. However the code should work.

Here's the directory from within PHPStorm:

[image: Directory]

and Here's the code:

[image]

The error happens in checkprimenumber.php in the routes folder. PHPStorm can find it within the IDE so there shouldn't be an issue.

I move all the code from a local drive to a Apache server (which has the same folder names in the project) the server does need a password to add directories and files so I don't know if there could be an issue there.

I don't know what the problem is as I doubt it's PHP and more Apache.

Some help would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try :  `require __DIR__.'/../CheckPriveValidate.php'`

Answer (score 0):

What if you would try to

```
require 'CheckPrimeValidate.php';
require 'CheckPrimeModel.php';
require 'CheckPrimeView.php';
```

I am  pretty sure, that if you should define the path from `index.php` prospective?

Or is that not the case?

Comment: No, this wouldn't work as there not in the same directory. I need to go back one to find the files. That's the reason for the '..' .

Answer (score 0):

Adding DIR before the file path works.

e.g.

```
require __DIR__.'/../CheckPrimeValidate.php';
```

Thanks to YvesLeBorg.